# How to find maximums' indexes by row with Numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

I have np 2d array and want to get indexes of max by row.

For example:

```
3 2 1 3 1
0 4 4 1 2
1 0 1 1 2
```

Maximum by row is
`[3, 4, 2]`.
Indexes are
`[(0,0) (0,3) (1,1) (1,2) (2,4)]`

I tried smth like this

`buf = np.apply_along_axis(lambda x:  zip(np.where(x == np.max(x))), axis=1, arr=B)`

or this

`buf = np.where(B == np.max(B,axis = 1))`

But it doesnt work.

Also I can't use loops (otherwise I wouldn't use numpy either)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After finding `max` you need set each max as one row then searching in base array like below:

```
>>> a = np.array([[3 ,2 ,1 ,3 ,1],[0, 4 ,4 ,1 ,2],[1, 0, 1, 1, 2]])

>>> np.max(a, axis=1)
array([3, 4, 2])

>>> np.max(a, axis=1)[:,None]
array([[3],
       [4],
       [2]])

>>> np.argwhere(a==np.max(a,1)[:,None])
array([[0, 0],
       [0, 3],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 2],
       [2, 4]])
```

If you want output like as `tuple` in your question you can try this:

```
>>> list(map(tuple, np.argwhere(a==np.max(a,1)[:,None])))
[(0, 0), (0, 3), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 4)]
```